# Can't get a basic Celery example working (Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//)

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I'm following the [First Steps with Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) tutorial but I can't seem to get it to function properly on my local machine. Looked at several other questions and followed their advice -- but still no luck.

Here's what I've done:

1. I've followed the [Using RabbitMQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#broker-rabbitmq) guide and started the server using `sudo rabbitmq-server`
2. I've saved the `tasks.py` example (below) in my working directory
3. I've started Celery using `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`, however, every time I run this command an error (below)

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I've also tried `app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost')` obviously replacing myuser, mypassword and myvhost to the values I created in step 1, but I'm getting a similar error.

Celery error:

```
[2020-04-11 16:52:50,196: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 92] Protocol not available.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get a basic scenario working by following the documentation, but to no success. So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you update your post with your operating system, the versions of celery & rabbitmq-server you're running, as well as the output of `sudo rabbitmqctl status`